# internationalization prints gibberish

Tags: java, web, internationalization, resourcebundle

I want to add i18n to my web project.

But I it prints gibberish, **before**:

[image]

**after**:

[image]

Here is page snippet of **page code**:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<c:set var="language"
       value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}"
       scope="session"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.java.task11.i18n.text"/>

<html lang="${language}">
<head>
    <title>Profile Info</title>
    <jsp:include page="parts/header.jsp"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid users-table">
    <%--navbar--%>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 table-nav">
            <jsp:include page="parts/navbar.jsp"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and snippet of `navbar.jsp`:

```
<li class="lang">
   <a href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>?language=${language == 'ua' ? 'en' : 'uk'}">
       ${language == 'ua' ? 'EN' : 'UKR'}
   </a>
</li>
```

Here is resource bundle looking:

[image]

I couldn't figure out why this happen?

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: The problem is with `ResourceBundle`. It cannot read property files in any other encoding than ISO-8859-1... If you are not stuck to using `ResourceBundle`, I have a library which can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

write in **unicode** symbols. For this:

**IDEA** -- has special "Transparent native-to-ASCII conversion" option (Settings > File Encoding).

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis here is that you use a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Unfortunately, and for backwards compatibility reasons, it cannot read property files in any other encoding than ISO-8859-1. And your properties file seems to be encoded in UTF-8.

Demonstration: let us take a file names `t.properties` at the root of the classpath, whose contents are encoded in UTF-8:

```
mouton = bêêêê
```

Now, let us try and print out this `mouton` key:

```
final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("t");
System.out.println(bundle.getString("mouton"));
```

Output:

```
bÃªÃªÃªÃª
```

Garbage.

This is why I have developped [this library](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple) which does not have this problem; it can read i18n property files in UTF-8. Demonstration:

```
// Reads in UTF-8 by default; can choose any encoding
final MessageBundle bundle = PropertiesBundle.forPath("t");
System.out.println(bundle.getMessage("mouton"));
```

Output:

```
bêêêê
```

Correct!

The "funny" thing is that this uses a [method which is available in `Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) (since 1.6) but which `ResourceBundle` doesn't use, nor does it provide a way to use it...

Comment: If I don't use Maven. Have I attach it as zip file to the project?

Comment: This and btf, yes; both are available for download on Bintray. But why don't you use gradle (which is better than maven)?

Comment: can you explain shortly how gradle is better than maven? and how it can be helpful here?

Comment: Build files are shorter to write, for one; and it can do everything maven does plus everything you _want_ it to do. You are not limited by what maven allows you to do ;)

Comment: I added this zip file to class path, but it keep printing gibberish.

Comment: Well, you have to use the API; if you keep using `ResourceBundle`, you'll keep having problems

Comment: `you have to use the API` what does this mean?